# How do I bring up (embedded) Linux on a Tegra Ventana development board?

Tags: linux, embedded, nvidia, tegra

I have a [Tegra Ventana development kit](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-ventana-development-kit), on which I want to run Linux.  (NVIDIA only makes Android 2.3 and 2.2 images available for the Ventana: see "Ventana Specific Downloads" at the bottom of http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-ventana-development-kit.)

I found [an announcement of the release of Linux For Tegra (L4T)](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/news/linux-tegra-released), which predates the release of the Ventana.  I also found [notice that L4T has been removed from NVIDIA's downloads page](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/forum/l4t-removed-downloads-page). So I guess if I want to run Linux on the Ventana (before NVIDIA eventually re-releases it) I'm going to have to build it myself.  (Though that might be made easier if I can follow the breadcrumbs left by the "many of the community have already taken various linux distributions and got them up and going..." mentioned in the [L4T announcement](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra/news/linux-tegra-released).)

How do I go about learning how to build Linux for this board?

I haven't been able to find any blog posts or mailing list entries from those people who have brought up various Linux distributions.

I did find http://tjworld.net/wiki/Android/Tegra/Linux/SourceCodeRepositoriesAndPatches#Linux, which gives me the Git URL to the Tegra tree (and the name of the maintainer).  Lower down on that same page is a pointer to the [linux-tegra mailing list](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-tegra).  But I didn't find anything like a link to "getting started" instructions in the mailing list.

I'm reading [Building Embedded Linux Systems, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529680) (and have skimmed through [Embedded Linux Primer, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137017839)), and perhaps I'll be able to figure it out for myself.  (Though I suspect I'm going to get stuck because of the lack of technical documentation on the Ventana.)  But I'd appreciate any advice to save me time.

Comment: Note: you can download the [Tegra Android Development Pack](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) which has support for Android 3.0 for Ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the people already running Ubuntu on Tegra 2 devices:

http://hdfpga.blogspot.com/2011/02/ubuntu-on-tegra-2-tablet-android.html

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=894960

Comment: In the first link, Ubuntu is booted using chroot, which I suppose is better than nothing.  But the second link looks like it's booting Ubuntu directly--perhaps I can learn how "jersacct" did used ViewSonic's sources to do that.

Comment: @Daryl Spitzer Do you just want to have linux running on it, or do you  want to "roll your own"?

Comment: I just want to have Linux running on it.  But Linux running using chroot is running as another process under Android, right?  So I expect the performance will be significantly worse than Linux running on the metal.